# Unable to release a maven module as git-tag fails loading commit file

Tags: maven-release-plugin, git-tag

I'm doing a nice and simple series of commands to release my maven modules:
mvn release:prepare
release:prepare -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DpushChanges=false to release a maven module.

But this command fails when tagging because it's unable to manage the comment file.

I go in my repo folder.  Within this I've got a 'project' with a master pom file with a few subproject.

I launched this from the windows command line.  mvn install runs fine.  git is the executable obtained from cygwin.  Running the same command with -X did not give me any information about why the .commit file does not get generated.

Any help is appreciated!

```
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli) @   Module0 ---
[INFO] Resuming release from phase 'scm-tag'
[INFO] Tagging release with the label v5.0.1...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git tag -F C:\Users\usern~1\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-1994697645.commit v5.0.1"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\usernamexyz\Documents\git\repo\project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Module1........................... FAILURE [  0.751 s]
[INFO] Module2..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Module3........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Module4............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Module5.................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.414 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-26T23:01:07+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/244M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli) on project Module0: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-tag command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: could not open or read 'project/C:\Users\usern~1\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-1994697645.commit': No such file or directory
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

A colleague in the office hinted me in the right direction.

I was using the git from cygwin and as soon as I changed for Git for windows (https://git-for-windows.github.io/) this passed.

I saw that my git commands were followed so I thought I was good but it seems something in the background does not manage well the Windows/Linux path name well.